# gtmetrix Specify image dimensions in a responsive website layout

Tags: css, html

I got an F on gtmetrix for 'Specify image dimensions'.
My website has the css handling all the width's and height's so that it can be responsive on various devices. If i specify the dimensions in html, then I cannot adjust them.

Is there a way to overcome this gtmetrix error? I was thinking of using JS to remove the html portion `width="" height=""`

Comment: Are you using @media queries to define the dimensions? Please show the CSS you're using.

Comment: yeah @media (max-width: 799px) { ... } you can view the css in design.bragdeal.com

Comment: Please post the CSS here or on jsfiddle. max-width doesn't set specific widths.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/s06yju2r/1/ just a quick example of how I style my whole website

Comment: Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use width and height specifications to scale images on the fly. If an image file is actually 60 x 60 pixels, don't set the dimensions to 30 x 30 in the HTML or CSS. If the image needs to be smaller, scale it in an image editor and set its dimensions to match (see Optimize images for details.)

Be sure to set the dimensions on the element itself, or a block-level parent. If the parent is not block-level, the dimensions will be ignored. Do not set dimensions on an ancestor that is not an immediate parent.